# query to get total amount, avg, and quantity for the following table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

How to write SQL query or stored procedure to get for the following table?

```
TRANCODE | SECTYPE | QUANTITY | TRADEAMOUNT
BY          CSEU     1609         19999.87 
SL          CSEU      609         7094.85
```

SQL query calculation:

```
QTY 1609-609=1000
AVG = 19999.87/1609 =12.43
TRADEAMONUT = QTY * AV = ?
```

Using SUM of quantity:

```
SUM 
      ( CASE 
        WHEN  TranCode ='by' THEN  CAST(Quantity as FLOAT)
        WHEN  TranCode ='ss' THEN  CAST(Quantity as FLOAT)
        WHEN  TranCode ='sl' THEN  CAST(Quantity as FLOAT) * -1
        WHEN  TranCode ='cs' THEN  CAST(Quantity as FLOAT) * -1     
  END)
```

How to do it in a SQL query to using math calculation?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: Iam using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 ...

Comment: Not clear. Could you post source data, your query, the results you are getting and the expected results?